# Numerous MVC controller instantiations of the same controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-treeview

I'm novice in MVC with c# and I'm wondering why the controller instance constructor will be called frequently (that means more than once).

I have created a typical view based on a layout page. Within the layout page, I'm calling a Kendo TreeView.I'm also using AutoFac and I have added the following instruction to my Global.asax according to AutoFac MVC instruction:

```
builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
```

If I'm debugging, the controller instance constructor which is using the view from above is getting called as soon as the Kendo TreeView is being processed. I can understand if the controller action is called for providing the Kendo TreeView datasource, but I'm not understanding the several calls of this instance constructor. I assumed that there is already an instance of the controller.

Does anyone know if a numerous instance constructor execution of the same controller is normal or is there an error in my coding in general, for instance, I should maybe not place the Kendo Treeview in a layout, maybe in a partial view?

Yours
Stephan

Comment: You have not shown your view, but the controller is initialized every time a request is made to one of its methods so it will be initialized when the request is made to return the view, and again if your `Kendo TreeView datasource` is making a ajax call to a method in the same controller.

Comment: If the treeview control has logic to determine whether each node should be made visible/invisible depending on the `AuthorizeAttribute`, then it will create a controller instance for each node in order to check whether the current user has access to it. Controller constructors should be kept lightweight - they should contain nothing more than guard clauses and assignment of services. Every user request instantiates a new controller instance so your application will perform poorly if you are trying to construct something every time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Stephen and NightOwl888. I will avoid now creating new instances of other objects within controller's constructor method.

Is it in general a good idea to use AutoFac and register the Controller class as Singleton in order to reuse already created controllers (maybe because I have properties which I won't to reload again) ?